# How to generate HTTP 1.1 header to stream video

Tags: http, http-1.1

What are the HTTP 1.1 header to stream video from a HTTP server ? Currently i am sending

transfer-Encoding : chunked

This runs well in flash video player in  google chrome , but fails to load in firefox.